# Marking Cython as a Build Dependency?

Tags: python, pip, cython, distutils, pypi

There is a Python package with a setup.py that reads thusly:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
  name = 'fastahack',
  ext_modules=[
    Extension("fastahack.cfastahack",
              sources=["fastahack/cfastahack.pyx", "lib/Fasta.cpp", "lib/split.cpp"],
              libraries=["stdc++"],
              include_dirs=["lib/"],
              language="c++"),
    ],
    package_data = {'lib': ['*.pyx', "*.c", "*.h", "README.rst"]},
    package_dir = {"fastahack": "fastahack"},
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    packages = ['fastahack', 'fastahack.tests'],
    author = "Brent Pedersen",
    author_email="bpederse@gmail.com",
    #test_suite='nose.collector'
)
```

This setup.py can't be imported if Cython is not installed. As far as I know, importing setup.py is how tools like pip figure out the dependencies of a package. I want to set up this package so that it could be uploaded to PyPI, with the fact that it depends on Cython noted, so that Cython will be downloaded and installed when you try to "pip install fastahack", or when you try to "pip install" directly from the Git repository.

How would I package this module so that it installs correctly from the Internet when Cython is not installed? Always using the latest version of Cython would be a plus.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify Cython as a build dependency using [PEP-518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) project specification.

In the file `pyproject.toml` (in the same directory as `setup.py`) insert:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "Cython"]
```

Cython will then be installed before building your package.

<strike>Note that (currently) you need to pass `--no-use-pep517` to `pip install` if you are installing your package locally as editable (ie with `--editable` or `-e`)</strike> [setuptools v64](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v64-0-0) supports editable installs with pyproject.toml builds

Answer (score 4):

My standard template for setup.py:

```
have_cython = False
try:
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext
    have_cython = True
except ImportError:
    from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

if have_cython:
    foo  = Extension('foo', ['src/foo.pyx'])
else:
    foo  = Extension('foo', ['src/foo.c'])

setup (
   ...
   ext_modules=[foo],
   cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext}
```

And don't forget to provide extention .c files with package - that will allow users to build module without installing cython.

Comment: This isn't really what was asked for, though; the goal was to automatically install cython as a dependency ...

Comment: @SamB, do you have any update on making cython as a dependency?

Comment: @zyxue: No, I didn't find a way to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `try` and `except` for the `Cython` import and modify your `setup` based on whether or not your import succeeds.  Look at the [setup.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/f18378dc5af59c137e3579ff83806296c2222321/setup.py#L79) of Pandas for an [example](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/f18378dc5af59c137e3579ff83806296c2222321/setup.py#L371)